# Do I need to ask permission to read Contact data if my app only accesses the contact data read-only?

Tags: ios, permissions, contacts

My iOS App reads contact data from the device's contacts file but it does not write data to the file.

Do I need to ask the user's permission to do such read-only access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nscontactsusagedescription

yess this says you have to if you are accessing user contacts which means even if it is just read and not write